# Book about boy who goes to a magical academy

Tags: story-identification, books

Boy who grew up in a secluded cabin with his Uncle who pretends to be his father. His mother was killed by the son of the Werewolf alpha and his real father retaliated and killed the werewolf out of anger. He was then imprisoned in Jotunheim i believe. The son then grows up without learning any magic but instead learns to fight. He tries to get into the academy where his Uncle went and eventually gets in. During the book he goes on a rescue mission from the school with his two friends to save the daughter of the werewolf alpha and eventually saves her with his friends, only to have one of his friends die at the hand of the vampire leader who captured the werewolf girl. The boy loses control and ends up destroying every vampire in sight in grief over the loss of his friend.

The only other detail I remember is the boy has something in his brain I believe it was a dragon long dead who resides within the boy. He gains two blades that are bound to him. That’s about it though.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]. There's some good _plot detail_ here; please could you [edit your question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/265194/edit) to include some of the stuff in [this checklist](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) ?